# Present participle - seeing

Tags: american-english, british-english, present-participles

I red somewhere that "see" doesn't form present participle. Is it true? For exemple in sentence:

1. I'm seeing my doctor today.

We use -ing form. Can we call it present participle in sentence or should we call it differently?

Comment: You may benefit from asking this on our sister site, English Language Learners.

Comment: (1) The _ing_-form 'seeing' is commonly used in both more nounlike (seeing is believing) and  verbal (I don't like what I'm seeing) contexts. (2) The expression 'I am seeing John' is not a correct paraphrase of 'I see John' or (more commonly) 'I can see John'. But it can be used to describe a one-off or recurring visit (as with your doctor example), or it can be used when describing a perhaps unexpected view on a monitor say.

Comment: "nounlike" you mean gerund? In your example "seeing is believing" is "seeing" the gerund in this case?

Comment: Don't confuse the meanings of *see*=meet and *see*=eyesight; ability to see. E.g. "I can see a chicken crossing the street" VS "I'm seeing my friend for a coffee" The first sentence is not normally phrased in the present continuous wheras the second "see" can. Your example is see=meeting someone/having an appointment

Comment: On the review queue we don't see answers that have been posted 10 hours earlier—oops! Colin Fine's answer is as ever impeccable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arcadio. The information you have is garbled.

*See* certainly does form a present participle *seeing*. However, the use of the continuous tenses (eg *I am seeing*) is somewhat restricted:

1. In its primary meaning *see* tends not to take a continuous tense, like other verbs of perception. So *I see the book* is much more common than *I am seeing the book*. It *can* take a continuous form, when the current and temporary nature of the perception is being emphasised (eg *I'm sitting here watching the video. I'm seeing him stand up. Now he leaves the room.*) but it is not  normal usage in most varieties of English.
2. But your example uses *see* in a different sense, something like *have an appointment with*. In this sense, *see* behaves like a normal verb, and there is no restriction on using a continuous tense. *I'm seeing my doctor today* is perfectly normal English.

Comment: Seeing also meets going out with someone on a regular basis.  "Did you know John is seeing Mary?"